# regular Export on Magento 1.9.1 exporting custom options 12 times

Tags: custom-options, ce-1.9.1.0, importexport

Magento 1.9.1

We are exporting products from Magento 1.9.1 and importing them into Magento 1.9.4

When this regular export/import was done - I noticed that custom options showed up 12 times. I thought it was due to my multiple times of trying the import so I deleted all imported products and started again with a clean file. When the import finished, the product once again had the custom options 12 times on the front and back end. I then checked the original exported file and it is there 12 times!

**What can be done to resolve this?**